# Git log output log file

Tags: git, logging

I am doing an assignment in a university course and I am using Git as version control for this assignment. The game I have been working on is complete. However, along with the hand in I would like to submit the Git log, effectively showing my progress during the time I have been working on it.

I have tried this:

```
git log --stat > log.log
```

But it more or less just gives me very unreadable stuff. What is a command so that I can get a nice formatting on this?

Comment: What do you want the output to focus on?  The commit messages?  The branching?  The dates?  The files?  The changes?

Comment: What do you mean by *"very unreadable stuff"*? In what way?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I would recommend using a different format than the default. My usual choice is a summary with the graph, but a one-line summary alone usually does the trick.

**Option 1:** *One-line summary with a graph*

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s' --graph > log.log
```

***Results in:***

```
* 2d3acf9 : ignore errors from SIGCHLD on trap
*   5e3ee11 : Merge branch 'master' of git://github.com/dustin/grit
|\
| * 420eac9 : Added a method for getting the current branch.
* | 30e367c : timeout code and tests
* | 5a09431 : add timeout protection to grit
* | e1193f8 : support for heads with slashes in them
|/
* d6016bc : require time for xmlschema
```

**Option 2:** *One-line summary without a graph*

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h was %an, %ar, message: %s' > log.log
```

***Results in:***

```
a6b444f was Scott Chacon, 5 days ago, message: dammit, this is the second time this has re
49d77f7 was Scott Chacon, 8 days ago, message: modified index to create refs/heads if it i
9764edd was Hans Engel, 11 days ago, message: Add diff-lcs dependency
e1ba1e3 was Hans Engel, 11 days ago, message: Add dependency for Open4
0f87b4d was Scott Chacon, 12 days ago, message: merged recent changes
```

You can find more formatting options in the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats).

Comment: I´m getting Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: One can find the format placeholders at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log. Search for sub-heading "pretty formats"

Comment: FYI: I know this answer is old but the "docs" link is broken.  I'm certainly not going to do what others have done to me: Down vote my answer like 3, 4 or 5+ years later due to the link going bad later in time.  I've submitted an edit to point to git-scm.com (https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) FYI.

Comment: Invalid object name %h

Answer (score 16):

Try this line

`git log > log.txt`

Comment: This is the base answer, all I needed.

Comment: git log alone will show tags and branches (all branches, including remote branches) on the console.  However, git log > log.txt will not have those tag/branch information.  I really want to know how to make them the same (i.e. get output with tag/branch infos)

Answer (score 7):

```
git log --oneline --decorate > log.txt
```