# How do I export a git log to a text file?

Tags: git

I want to export the log of all commits in a repo to a text file, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git log output log file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063407/git-log-output-log-file)

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You'll just need to disable the pager.

```
git --no-pager log > log.txt
```

If you want to format it to look nicer, you can use [parameters](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-log) of git log.

Comment: For some reason saving it like that it skips the header information for branches, any idea how i can get it? ex.: commit b28b1ae828ee87ffdc675dc1de299b51d3eb2ea2 (origin/master, ....etc, when i save it i dont see origin/master anymore

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch `--decorate` can be added to get that, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55203481/git-log-oneline-gives-head-information-that-is-lost-when-piping-or-redirecting)

Answer (score 29):

Have you tried `git log > log.txt` ?

Comment: In the present working directory from where you ran the command.

Comment: It works like a charm. It also works when trying to save information from the `status` command.

Answer (score 27):

```
git log | clip
```

copies to clipboard, then paste to a textfile.

(Especially if you have the problem of line-ending and thus by this method you can copy and paste it in a Microsoft word document(.docx);
so there would be a new line for each commit!!!)

Comment: This seems to be the easiest way for Windows users to get around the Unix line-ending issue that writing straight to a file presents.

Comment: Oh that is so cool. I've been using Windows since the early '90s and I never realised you could pipe to `clip` board. I always used to redirect to a file then open that in notepad etc. This is a game-changer!

Answer (score 12):

You may use the `>` symbol send the output to a file. For example:

```
git log > commits.txt
```

Answer (score 11):

```
git log --before="2019-2-23" --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%ae","%aD","%s",' --shortstat --no-merges | paste - - - > log.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

Its been long since this question was asked and by that time things have been evolved.

***But***, it is very interesting that all answers here are correct but not really addressing a post ***command error*** which is also very common. Lets try to understand . . . .

Who knew it was super easy. Run a simple command

```
git log -p --all > git_log.txt
```

but then I strucked on an error

```
> warning: inexact rename detection was skipped due to too many files.
> warning: you may want to set your diff.renameLimit variable to at least 2951 and retry the command.
```

and we had a problem. The output file was half a gig.

We just wanted the first half of 2018 which we are able to do with `--after` and `--until`

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ad - %an: %s" --after="2018-01-01" --until="2018-06-30" > git_log.txt
```

This worked nicely for our purposes and was nice to know that we could change the format if need be.

Answer (score 4):

You can make log report more clearly, by

(1) setting number of latest commits (for example, in below command, we get latest 50 commits, you can change it to 100, 500, etc.)

(2) display long commit in one line
This command is display commit log in current branch:

```
 git log --oneline -50 > log50_latest_commits.txt
```

(3) If you want display commit at all branch

```
 git log --all --oneline -50 > log50_latest_commits.txt
```

Generated text file will stand at the current directory.

Reference: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

(tested on `git version 2.11.0.windows.1` and it works on many other versions of Git)

Answer (score 3):

**In my case i found this was helpful**

`git log --after="2020-3-20" --pretty=format:'Author : %an %nDate/Time :  %aD%nCommit : %s'   | paste  > log.txt`

This will generate :

Author : your name

Date/Time : Commit Date time

Commit : Commit message

Comment: this just gave me a blank log.txt file even when I update the year

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me with `Git Bash` on `Windows 7`:

`git log > /C/Users/<user-name>/Desktop/git-log.txt`

**replace `<user-name>` with your `user name`.**

The file will be exported to your `Desktop` from where you can `read` it.

Good Luck...

Answer (score 1):

I found this article that could help you. [Article of how generate a changelog](https://herewecode.io/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-git-what-is-a-changelog-and-how-to-generate-it/)
One tool that you could use is changelog

```
npm install generate-changelog -g
changelog generate
```

It will create a well formed CHANGELOG.md file.

Greetings.

Comment: not everyone has npm installed

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.
if you don't matter save a file you need the open terminal

```
cd {your git repository}
git log > your_file_name.txt
```

if you need a special directory, just write all path in the right side, like this

```
cd {your git repository}
git log > /home/user/logs/your_file_name.txt
```

This directory, for example, you could use any one of your needs.
I write a log like this just now.

[This example show how to write a text in a file via bash](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-append-to-file/)

Comment: Identical to existing answers.

Comment: Maybe, but i do this actions right now, and explain myself example

Comment: Good. But Stack Overflow is not your personal blog. It is an encyclopedia, and this entry is already written.

Comment: Thanks for your review. Just I want an answer for the question which not have answear since 2013 year.