# How to save "git log" in a file?

Tags: git

Let's say I want to see all git changes from my repository. What I do is to execute the following command on the windows console:

```
git log --oneline --decorate
```

So I can see the complete history on the console.
But what if I want to save it in a file, to send it to the client?
I know I can capture the output of the console doing some coding, but I think there must be a way to simply save it in a file. Something like `git log --oneline --decorate --SaveToFile` or something like that
How can something like this be done?

Comment: `git log --oneline --decorate > file.txt`

Comment: Post it as an answer so i can give you that green stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting comment as answer:

You can use simple stream redirection to achieve it.

`git log --oneline --decorate > file.txt`

Comment: use also --no-pager to get the complete output http://stackoverflow.com/a/10330711/1136458