# How to get all git logs at once?

Tags: git, github

Right now after run `git log --all`, git return me only 25 recent logs and then I must to press `Enter` to get another one log. So, how to get all of the logs at once?

Thanks for any help

Comment: How about `--no-pager`? Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330425/how-do-i-export-a-git-log-to-a-text-file

Comment: What do you mean? I get them piped into `less`, maybe you want to save them into a file and read them with something else? git log --all > out.txt

Comment: `--no-pager` is all what I need, thanks @Martin !